# Linear Optimization Problem with a constraint on the cost functin

Tags: linear-programming

Is there a known algorithm ( similar to simplex algorithm) that solves the following problem: 
Maximize $c^Tx$ subject to the constraints $Ax\leq b$ and $c^Tx\leq \alpha$. It would be nice if you can provide a link to an article or software implementation of such problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well of course, all you do is add $c^T$ as a row to your $A$ matrix, and $\alpha$ to your $b$ vector. That is,
$$\bar{A}\triangleq \begin{bmatrix} A \\ c^T \end{bmatrix} \quad \bar{b}\triangleq \begin{bmatrix} b \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}$$
And then you solve using any preferred algorithm:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & c^T x \\
\text{subject to} & \bar{A} x \leq \bar{b}
\end{array}$$
Here's how this works: let $\alpha_{\max}$ be the solution to the original problem (without the extra $c^Tx\leq\alpha$ constraint), and let $\alpha_{\min}$ be the solution to the *minimization* $$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & c^T x \\
\text{subject to} & A x \leq b
\end{array}$$
(Note: it's possible one of these extremes will be infinite.)
Now select any value $\alpha\in[\alpha_{\min},\alpha_{\max}]$ and add your extra constraint $c^Tx\leq \alpha$ as I've shown above. When you solve this modified model, the optimal point $x^*$ will achieve exactly $c^Tx^*=\alpha$.

Again, I'm sorry for misreading the problem earlier! I hope this clarifies matters.

Comment: because sometimes you don't care about global maximums but only about local ones. I am not interested in any maximum but only maximum in a certain region.

Comment: Why must the modified program be unfeasible if $c^Tx^*>\alpha$? Clearly $x^*$ cannot be optimal, as it is not feasible, but there could exist a different optimal solution for the modified program.

Comment: so what you're saying that with your modification if there is no solution to the original model there will be no solution to your modification?

Comment: Of course I am asking about it but you solved my problem so for that I am very thankful and I am giving you all the credit! But suppose that we found $x*$ in the original problem such $c^Tx^{*}>\alpha$ does it mean that if I will use the new set up (with \bar(A) it will give me a point $x_0$ and the maximum will be exactly $\alpha?$ This exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: I'm afraid I misread your problem as a minimization, not a maximization. My approach to adding a row to $A$ and $b$ still works, but most of what I said before is irrelevant. I'm sorry for leading you astray; I'm deleting many of my comments above. @Daryl, now I understand your confusion too.

Comment: No that's fine. I am happy with your trick. I didn't realize that I can add constraints satisfied by the cost function itself. The trick you suggested should do the job.

Comment: Great. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: This problem arises naturally in financial planning. You have an existent portfolio with certain weights and projected returns for each of these weights. You like to achieve a maximal certain return  below a certain return threshold while keeping control of how you change the weights ( not too much trading). So I hope you can see that the restriction I introduced is natural ( total return of the portfolio is just the weighted average of the projected returns)